# Optimize my website for above 1024 resolution

Tags: css, react-bootstrap

My website is not working properly on above 1024 resolutions even though my div containers has it's width set to 100vw. When I view it on large displays the div container looks small. From what I know 100vw is 100% width of the screen. Can someone explain it.

Comment: Please post your code which demonstrates the issue instead of trying to describe it.

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask] and [mre]. This is not a place for abstract “anyone know what that could be” discussions - you need to show a proper example of the code you are having problems with. (And before you just drop a link now, read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/ as well please.)

Comment: Bootstrap’s `container` class elements have a max-width set by default, _maybe_ that is your issue here. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/overview/#containers The `container-fluid` class exists to provide a container element without any max-width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .container, .container-sm {
    max-width: 1024px;
  }
}
```

This is the reason it wont grow above **1024px** until it reaches **1140px**.This is **by default media query** for container in **bootstrap**.

Comment: This solves my problem.